# hashing 160 bit to a fixed number of integer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, hmac

i want to hash an output of keyed-hash message authentication code (HMAC) to a fixed number of integer (10-12 digits) what is the best Node JS

Answer (score 0):

probably [***`bcrypt`***](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) is what you are looking for.

You should be able to hash it like:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const myPlaintextPassword = 's0/\/\P4$$w0rD';
const someOtherPlaintextPassword = 'not_bacon';
```

Another one is [bcrypt-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs) and you might do something like this:

#### Synchronous

```
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync("bacon");

bcrypt.compareSync("bacon", hash); // true
bcrypt.compareSync("veggies", hash); // false
```

#### Asynchronous

```
bcrypt.hash("bacon", null, null, function(err, hash) {
    // Store hash in your password DB.
});
```

<sub>***Example code taken from the provided source.***</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Jai, i'm little novice to this can you please tell me what will be the output of the bcrypt.hashSync("bacon"); is it a numeric digit, what will be the length for 160 Bit message